# Google Apps Script only works when manually triggered, not by any other trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm a bit struggling to understand this matter:
My code meant to delete rox X if the colour of a cell in row X column Y is RED (f4c7c3).
For example :

[image: Delete Row 7]

The code works great thanks to a few questions I saw around here that helped me make it better, but it will only work when I click run. If I'm using any trigger (I want to use a time-driven trigger every day between midnight and 1 AM, but I've tried them all), it shows that it was completed, but nothing happens to the spreadsheet.
[image: Executions]

Here is my code, I'd appreciate your help with that issue:

```
function DeleteRow(column,color) {   //Delete row if the color in the Date column is F4C7C3
  var column = (typeof(column)!='undefined')?column:4;  
  var color = (typeof(color)!='undefined')?color:'#f4c7c3'; 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Ichlawob5EHzSK4ljRSJfViugFWugTzHOMId3q5LL6w");
  var sht = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]); 
  var rng = ss.getDataRange();
  var rngA = rng.getBackgrounds()
  for(var i=rngA.length-1;i>-1;i--)
  {
    if(rngA[i][column-1]==color)
    {
      sht.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

BTW, just got a summary that shows the error even though the executions indicate successfully-

[image: Errors]

Comment: Onedit trigger can not be fired by another script

Comment: The email shown in the question looks to be a daily summary so it might not reflect the current authorization status of your script. When debugging installable triggers the best is to set the trigger notifications to be sent immediately.

By the other hand the function name shown in the question code (`DeleteRow `) doesn't match the function name shown in the images (`DeleteRowForExpiredPermits`) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the line:

```
var column = (typeof(column)!='undefined')?column:4;
```

To:

```
var column = (typeof(column)=='number')?column:4;
```

Or just:

```
var column = 4;
```

**Explanation**

Whenever you're firing a function via a trigger the function gets an 'event object' as a first and only argument. You're actually calling `DeleteRow(e)` instead of `DeleteRow()`. Where the `e` is the event object. It's not `undefined` and its not a number.